# Как продублировать layout?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

С каждым нажатием кнопки "+ Новий елемент" llElement должен дублироваться. Не знаю как правильно описать именно этот процесс в activity. Должно примерно получиться так, как на скриншоте выделено красным.

**xml:**

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/AllElements"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Cargo: "
                android:textSize="26sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llElement"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:visibility="visible">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etElement"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="10"
                    android:textSize="20sp"/>

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/cbDelete"
                    android:layout_width="5dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
                <!--android:onClick=" "/>-->

            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnNewElement"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:text="+ Новий елемент"
                android:onClick="addNewElement"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

[image: Фрагмент с программы Google Keep][image: Фрагмент моего приложения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вы хотите сделать именно таким образом, то вынесите

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llElement"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etElement"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cbDelete"
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <!--android:onClick=" "/>-->

</LinearLayout>
```

В отдельный `xml` файл. И добавляйте его или через `include` (в `xml`), либо так (программно):

```
View v = LayoutInflater.from(YourActivity.this).inflate(item.xml, null)
myContainerForViews.addView(v);
```

`myContainerForViews` - пустой `LinearLayout` добавленный вместо удаленного.
Причем ваши `View` лучше добавлять в ArrayList, чтобы потом иметь доступ к их элементам через `views.get(position).findViewById(R.id.etElement)`.

**НО. Это не самое лучшее решение и не самая правильная организация кода.**

Рекомендую вам переделать всё под `RecyclerView`, в котором вы используете вашу разметку как item, и массив данных. Тогда добавление и обновление данных будет простым и элегантным:

```
myList.add(new Item());
recycler.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Но если вам просто "надо написать чтобы все работало" сработает и первый вариант. Только учитывайте, что при n-элементе ваши остальные `View` (и кнопка) уйдут за экран. Поэтому придется оборачивать все в `ScrollView`

Answer (score 2):

Я бы предложил вам оформить этот участок программы в виде RecyclerView. Тогда добавление нового элемента будет выполняться через адаптер, и вы сможете считывать данные с этой ячейки, а не просто добавить ее на экран. Вот неплохой пример https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/, но если что, вы без труда найдете кучу других.